# Efficiently change an array of bools to string - Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift

I am working on a quiz project and trying to convert an array of bools to an array of strings so that I can present the user with their answers. I have tried to enumerate the question array and pull out all the users answers and the correct answers and append them to a new array.

users answers go to userAnswers

correct answers go to correctAnswers

Then it calls a function checkResults that will check how many answers the user got wrong or right.

This is where I got stuck. I used a map function to compare the 2 arrays and give me a new array back called answer. If the answers matched the it would return true and if they didn`t it would return false. I am not entirely sure how to convert the results inside answer to an array of strings to present to the user.

```
// My Arrays

class QuizQuestion {

    let question: String!
    let answer: Bool!
    let explanation: String!
    var usersAnswer: Bool?

    init(question: String, answer: Bool, explanation: String) {
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer
        self.explanation = explanation
    }
}

let questions = [

    QuizQuestion(question: "Do I like coffee?", answer: true, explanation: "Because it's awesome!"),
    QuizQuestion(question: "Is bacon god's gift to mankind?", answer: true, explanation: "Because it's awesome!"),
    QuizQuestion(question: "Should I take a nap right now?", answer: true, explanation: "You gotta review some code!"),
]

var userAnswers: [Bool] = []
var correctAnswers: [Bool] = []


// Submit Functions


func checkResults() {
     let answer = map(zip(correctAnswers, userAnswers)){$0.0 == $0.1}        
     var finalResults = answer.map({"The following answer is \($0)"})        
}

@IBAction func submitAll(sender: UIButton) {
     let hasAnsweredAllQuestions = questions.reduce(true) { (x, q) in x && (q.usersAnswer != nil) }
     println("has user answered all questions?: \(hasAnsweredAllQuestions)")
     for (index, _) in enumerate(questions) {
         userAnswers.append(questions[index].usersAnswer!)
         correctAnswers.append(questions[index].answer)
     }
     if correctAnswers.count == 3 {
         checkResults()
     }
}
```

Comment: You should post how your arrays look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func checkResults() {
    let answer = map(zip(correctAnswers, userAnswers)){
        ($0.0 == $0.1) ? "correct" : "wrong"
    }
    var finalResults = answer.map({"The following answer is \($0)"})
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to "change" the bools into a string you can use `map()` again:

```
let answer  = [1,2,2]
let correct = [6,7,2]

func checkResults() {

    let answers = map(zip(correct, answer)) { $0.0 == $0.1 }
    let results = answers.map { $0 == true ? "You answered right!" : "Nope, wrong!" }

    map(results) { println($0) }
}
```

This prints out:

```
Nope, wrong!
Nope, wrong!
You answered right!
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Both this and the other solution taught me a lot!